# How to run a keras with tensorflow 2 model on a machine with multiple CPU?

Tags: multithreading, keras, google-cloud-platform, deep-learning, tensorflow2.0

How can I train a keras model with tensorflow 2 backend on a machine with multiple CPUs and GPUs on GCP? Does tf handle the process itself on backend? If so how can I verify it? Any simple sample code is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways you can use GCP in order to train a model.

Here are some of them (with different levels of Google management):

1 - You can create a  [Compute Engine Instance](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/quickstart-linux) (you can choose how much processing and the type of CPU's / GPU's attached to it you want) and do the training there. Everything is managed through SSH and there is no graphical interface or python dependencies installed.

2 - You can create an [AI Platform Notebook](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/notebooks/docs) and it will already be created with the desired tensorflow version and Jupyterlab installed. You can access it through Jupyterlab interface or SSH it. You also have the option to choose between processing options here.

3 - You can have [AI Platform train](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/training/docs/training-jobs) do the training online for you. [Here](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/training/docs/using-gpus#compute-engine-machine-types-with-gpu) you have the documentation referred to the CPU / GPU usage during online training.

A generally used pipeline is [develop on AI Notebooks > train locally using AI Local Train and a subset of data > train online with AI Platform Train and full dataset to get model deployed]